# How to solve Race condition in setting React state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

I have component that have state as object

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
  input, 
  output: '', 
  enableCopyToClipboard: true,
}
```

When listen to Observable I do following:

```
  // reset state before loading stream
  setData({ 
    ...data, 
    output: '',
    enableCopyToClipboard: false,
  });

  loadingStream(request).subscribe((response) => {
    resText.push(response.text);
    setData({ 
      ...data, 
      output: resText.join(''), 
    });
  });
```

Problem is my **enableCopyToClipboard** variable in state stays true when it should be false while streaming is ongoing. No idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **callback** function to set the new `data`. So you'll always have the *most up to date* version of the state. This prevents the override of the *old* version of the state.

```js
// reset state before loading stream
setData((prevData) => ({
  ...data,
  output: "",
  enableCopyToClipboard: false,
}));

loadingStream(request).subscribe((response) => {
  resText.push(response.text);
  setData((prevData) => ({
    ...prevData,
    output: resText.join(""),
  }));
});
```

You could also set the `enableCopyToClipboard` to `false` by default on the `subscribe`.

```js
loadingStream(request).subscribe((response) => {
  resText.push(response.text);
  setData((prevData) => ({
    ...prevData,
    enableCopyToClipboard: false,
    output: resText.join(""),
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple state updates in the same render, as well as state updates *within a closure*, can cause this problem.  An often recommended approach is to use the callback version of state updates.  For example:

```
setData(d => ({ 
  ...d, 
  output: '',
  enableCopyToClipboard: false,
}});

loadingStream(request).subscribe((response) => {
  resText.push(response.text);
  setData(d => ({ 
    ...d, 
    output: resText.join(''), 
  }));
});
```

In the case of state updates within a closure, the difference here is that the `data` variable isn't being captured by that closure and there's no dependency on it.  In the case of batched state updates, the difference here is that the callback uses the current state in the batch sequence rather than the state at the time of rendering.